# What are the hidden commands for the computer?

Tags: candy-box-2

The computer hints that there are extra special hidden commands. What are they?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The list of hidden commands on the computer is as follows:

- `no`
- `yes`
- `aniwey`
- `cedric`
- `17`
- `dixsept`
- `soinou`
- `42`
- `cp`
- `rm`
- `cd`
- `ls`
- `emacs`
- `vim`
- `vi`
- `nano`
- `startx`
- `mkdir`
- `sudo`
- `su`
- `lol`
- `pwd`
- `mv`
- `pacman`
- `tobias`
- `deinol`
- `dani`
- `godsturf`
- `mlp`
- `help command`

These were extracted directly from the source code.